Where are the binaries for images in odoo 12 postgresql
I am migrating a database with thousands of products from odoo12 running in docker, Trying to export large numbers of images using the Odoo web interface is not possible at all, the images after decoded from the base64 included in the csv exported from web interface are completely broken.
broken output sample
So plan B is to get the images from query straight outta the database on a csv, main problem is: im a total newb when it comes to psql, nevertheless here we go:
EDIT:
i was able to obtain products id, and name from this basic query:
SELECT "id","name" from product_template;

but images nowhere to be found.
after quite a few failed attempt of fetching the image from product_template i realize that images in Odoo12 are storaged actually inside the ir_attachment table, using the  "datas" field so, i modify my query to the following:
so i modify my query to the following:

Select "id", "res_name", "datas_fname" from ir_attachment WHERE res_model = 'product.template' and "datas_fname" is not null;

and i get the following query data sample
now the big question i have spent hours scratching my head on is: Where are the binaries?
heres a sample of the complete ir_attachments table with full rows using this query
Select * from ir_attachment WHERE res_model = 'product.template' and res_field = 'image' and 'db_datas' is not null

big query data sample
if someone could lend me a hand finding out where the actual image data is so i could extract it from a csv or making python script, i would be eternally grateful.
thanks.

The images are saved/stored in the filestore. The ir_attachment table usually holds only relative filepaths to Odoo's filestore. So migrating those files means migrating the filestore. In very simple migrations it just moving the whole folder from a to b.

Thank you very much for answering, i did found the filestore of this installation inside /opt/odoo/volumes/app/filestore... i still need to scrape the binaries into actual images cause they need them apart, i guess the best approach would be making an odoo module for that. thanks.
